# Fullcalendar plugin Javascript error on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I did not have enough knowledge about JavaScript, that is why I am asking this question. On my website's employee roster dashboard I got some javascript error when hovering on some dates, like the date 8th,9th and 7th september. onhover it is showing a box with 'null' error message. Can it be removed?

I am using 'full calendar' plugin to show this dates.

Here is my dashboard.
http://www.zaika.com.au/sarkar/ab7/index.php/dashboard

Comment: I'd like to say yes, but i can't recreate what you're describing, nothing happens.... unless you've already taken care of it

Comment: @Daemedeor I  have search for it over internet, but did not find any solution. and I do not have enough knowledge about JavaScript to solve this. But I am sure it is for that plugin. Can you help me please?

Comment: oh now i know why i couldn't reproduce it... one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a hover event to the server that is being called but the hack solution is to give this css, which essentially "gets rid of it" but its going to take longer to trace down the fullcalender intiation, i want to say this is the case of you calling an ajax to your server to request information on these events, but it's not quite clear where that is happening:

```
.tooltipevent{
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Okay I read through the file and found the offending js....

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ //re-initialize the calendar
            disableDragging: true,
            //header: h,
            header: {
                left: '<input type="text" value="subhash">',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next'
            },
            /* viewRender: function(view, element) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', 2014, 4, 24 );
             }, */
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            dayRender: function(date, cell){  
                if (date < futureBlockDate){ 
                    $(cell).addClass('fc-cell-overlay');
                }
                //$(cell).addClass('fc-cell-overlay')
            },
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

                var SelectedDate=(date.getFullYear() + '-'+number_change(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + number_change(date.getDate()));
                $('#start_date').val(SelectedDate); 
                $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", date);
                if(!$(this).hasClass('fc-cell-overlay')){ 
                $('#deleteEvent').hide();
                $('#title_popup').html('Create');
                $('#editId').val();
                $('#stack1_click').trigger('click');} 
            }, 
            eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) { 

                var unid=event.id;  
                var type=event.type;    
                if(type=="leave"){  
                    var reason = event.reason;
                    var startDate = new Date(event.start);
                    var endDate = new Date(event.end); 
                    var Start=(startDate.getFullYear() + '-'+number_change(startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + number_change(startDate.getDate()));
                    var End=(endDate.getFullYear() + '-'+number_change(endDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + number_change(endDate.getDate())); 

                    $('#editId').val(unid);
                    $('#reason').html(reason);
                    $('#start_date').val(Start);
                    $('#end_date').val(End);
                    $('#deleteEvent').show();
                    $('#title_popup').html('Update');
                    $('#stack1_click').trigger('click');
                }
            },
             events: {
                url: base_url+'employees/fetch_events', 
            },
            eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {  

                if(calEvent.message!="" && typeof(calEvent.message)!="undefined"){      
                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.message + '</div>'; 
                $("body").append(tooltip);
                $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
                }).mousemove(function(e) {
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
                });
                }
            },          
            eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
                 $(this).css('z-index', 8);
                 $('.tooltipevent').remove();
            }, 
        });
```

or more succulently this piece:

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {  

                if(calEvent.message!="" && typeof(calEvent.message)!="undefined"){      
                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.message + '</div>'; 
                $("body").append(tooltip);
                $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
                }).mousemove(function(e) {
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
                });
                }
            },
```

I don't know what you intend to do with calEvent.message but what you can do is change this if test to, so that all "falsy" values are ignored (including your test for empty strings, undefined and null) which will all produce a false:

```
if(calEvent.message)
```

Comment: for now it works for me. later I will change the plugin. Thanks

Comment: @web2tips I know you gave me the answer but i updated to change your js, this is in the /assets/template/scripts/index.js file, around line 220